Handle "Know your location" popup in truclient script
There is a multi factor authentication login page where when we enter username Nd password and click on login button getting "know your location" popup, to proceed to next page we need to handle the popup. How to handle or disable this popup in true client script . PFA popup image and help on this to overcome this issue.popup image

This is a system modal dialog, not a part of the browser.  There is nothing you can do inside of a virtual browser instance to escape out to the operating system to effect a system moda; dialog.
This is true for Openstext truclient
This is true for Tricentis Realbrowser.
This is true for Selenium.
You need a fully functional system functional testing client to operate a system modal dialog.

is there any other way to handle the popup in truclient

(a) Run a full OS functional testing client, such as QTP.   (b) Disable the location javascript in your testing environment.  (c) Built an HTTP virtual user instead of a TruClient virtual User
